# Eudiometer Problem?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In lab, students collect 42.6mL of N2 gas over water 24 C and 751 torr. The water in the eudiometer is 16.5 cm higher than the water outside.
Calculate the dry standard volume of N2?

I'm given the volume with water vapour i assume and i need to calculate the dry volume

"  The water in the eudiometer is 16.5 cm higher than the water outside. "

This sentence brings all the confusion, does someone has a picture that explains it? does it mean that the atmospheric pressure is higher by 16.5cm water, then i convert that to mmHg.
hence
PN2=Patm-P(difference)-Pwater

and then
PV=nRT
V=nRT/P
but still i have no moles, any hints?

Comment: @Poutnik so my sentence in the original post makes sense that atm pressure is higher by 16.5 cm H2O?

Comment: Ok 16.5cm H2O is 12.13mmHg=12.13torr
that means that the pressure of the gases is 751-12.13=738.87torr.

how from there i can get the volume of dry N2?


@Poutnik

Comment: I know im given the partial pressure of water vapour at a specific temperature so i can find the partial pressure of N2 alone, but still i dont have the dry volume or the moles, if i had the moles i can calculate the dry volume but i dont.

Comment: I guess you need not us to check if you can resolve simple arithmetic. Involve independent investigation and express it in the question, otherwise it could get closed for insufficient explicitly written effort of the OP. Hint - search for saturated vapour pressure table, in case the task expects the correction. Note that n=pV/(RT)

Comment: Yes but what is V? is it 42.6ml? because that is the volume of both gases (Water vapour and nitrogen) can i still use it? @Poutnik

Comment: Really ? Imagine it is not a wet gas, but air with O2 partial pressure 21 kPa. How would you calculate n for O2 ?

Comment: I truly apologize if i seem so dense, i dont know why this is confusing me, if i put 42.6 as volume i can get the number of moles of gas that exist in the volume which is N2 and H2O.

Comment: Surely you can. the question remains, if they expect water vapour correction or not, but I cannot decide that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113638/discussion-between-sharbel-damouni-and-poutnik).

Answer (score 2):

HINT - The picture below shows the situation.

[image]